# Downloading Object from Android's Amazon s3 makes file unreadable

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I'm trying to download a file I have in a bucket on Amazon s3. I'm using this code to debug, because I always get an EN0ENT / file not found when I try to read from the file in the end.

```
       String str_FilePathInDevice = "/sdcard/" + "/"
                + "RestoreFolderName" + "/" + "filname.extention";

        File file = new File(str_FilePathInDevice);

        String str_Path = file.getPath().replace(file.getName(), "");
        File filedir = new File(str_Path);

        try {
            filedir.mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
        }

        System.out.println(file.toString());
        System.out.println(file.canRead());
        System.out.println(file.length());

        TransferObserver observer2 = transferUtility.download(
                "arabianbucket",        /* The bucket to upload to */
                "demo.txt",       /* The key for the uploaded object */
                file        /* The file where the data to upload exists*/
        );

        System.out.println(file.toString());
        System.out.println(file.canRead());
        System.out.println(file.length());
```

the file.canread() ends up being flipped from true to false after the transferutility.download link. I'm not particularly sure why this is the case. Does anyone know how to successfully read from an object in Amazon s3? In my manifest, I've already flipped the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Might want to chat with this user - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768060/android-downloading-from-s3-aws

Comment: What is the path of the file that you're making? You should be using `getExternalStorage()` to get the folder you want

Comment: @cricket_007 i tried getExternalStorage, but i seem to still not be able to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

TransferUtility offers asynchronous transfers. In your code `transferUtility.download` initiates a download and the download happens in a background thread so as not to block the main thread. I don't recommend any file operation until the transfer is done. You can attach a listener to the observer and listens to status and progress changes. See [Store and Retrieve Files with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html) for more information.